# Looping rows of entitydatasource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, loops

First off.. I am new to asp.net and EF.

I have an EntityDatsource on my page I would like to loop through each row in the result set.

My goal is to dynamically build a page based on the values in the result set. Then to post the information back after it is edited by the user. My plan was to iterate each row on the page_load event. Currently I just have p-code in the area I would like to make this happen. The p-code is as follows

```
        // foreach (DataRow row in AvailableDeviceConfigDataSource.enti Rows)
        // {
        //   if sectionHeading <> lastSectionHeading
        //   { 
        //     lastSectionHeading = sectionHeading
        //     AddSettingsSection(sectionHeading)
        //   }
        //   AddRowObjects
        // }
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes across this and is interested, I did solve my issue a while ago and figured I should post my answer for the benefit of others....

```
        using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            string lastSectionHeading = "";
            bool isFirstHeading = true;

            var dynamicPageItems = context.view_dynamicPageItems;
            foreach (var item in dynamicPageItems)
            {
                if (item.IsActive == 1)
                {
                    if (!lastSectionHeading.Equals(item.CategoryId))
                    {
                        if (!isFirstHeading)
                            CloseSection();
                        lastSectionHeading = item.CategoryId;
                        AddSettingsSection(item.CategoryDescription);
                        isFirstHeading = false;
                    }
                    AddControl( item.DataType );
                }
            }
        }
```